# Sum up values based on key value in excel

Tags: excel-formula, sum

Based upon unique value, I need to pull sum of all rows against that particular value from another sheet.

Example:  In sheet 1 against project "ABC_1", I need to extract sum of all rows that has project value as "ABC_1".

Thanks for your help in advance.

Ganesh[image]

Comment: There's a SUMIF formula in excel that meets your demand

Comment: You can Resume your data with a Pivot Table, and group your data by project, and sum up the values

Answer (score 0):

In your example; B2 on Sheet1 should be `=SUMIF(Sheet2!C:C,A2,Sheet2!D:D)` which means, if you see (A2 value) on (Sheet2!C:C column), get sum of the values from (Sheet2!D:D column)

[more details in need](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Answer (score -1):

In Sheet1 column B use: `=SUMIF(Sheet2!C:C,@A:A,Sheet2!D:D)`

Comment: Dependent on your Excel version `@A:A` is equivalent to Column A, current Row. The `@` replaces the row number. Down voting without commenting why is not very nice. As you can see, the solution answer is actually the same logic.